# How can this SQL query be optimized? (Running on MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help on rewriting an SQL query that takes 26 seconds to run on an MySQL server.

The query is:

```
select
    c.countries_name,
    c.country_id,
    (SELECT
         count(1)
     FROM
         `fav_country`
     WHERE
         `country_id`=c.country_id
         and device_id='".$device_id."'
    ) as isFav,
    c.image,
    c.countries_iso_code,
    s.country
from
    station s
    left join countries c on c.country_id=s.country
where
    isactive=:isactive 
group by
    s.country
```

I have tried rewriting it with two left/right joins but to no avail.

Basically, we have three tables, countries, fav_country and station, the common field is the country id (countries.country_id, fav_country.countr_id and station.country)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you additionally share your table schema showing the columns and possible indexes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the query you want optimized:

```
select c.countries_name, c.country_id,
       (select count(1)
        from fav_country fc
        where fc.country_id = c.country_id and 
              fc.device_id = ?  -- use a parameter!
        ) as isFav,
        c.image, c.countries_iso_code
from station s left join
     countries c
     on c.country_id = s.country 
where s.isactive = :isactive
group by s.country;
```

First, avoiding the outer aggregate is very helpful.  I would replace it with exists:

```
select c.countries_name, c.country_id,
       (select count(1)
        from fav_country fc
        where fc.country_id = c.country_id and 
              fc.device_id = ?
        ) as isFav,
        c.image, c.countries_iso_code
from countries c
where exists (select 1
              from station s
              where s.country = c.country_id and
                    s.isactive = :isactive
             );
```

Then for this query, you want indexes on:

- `station(country, isactive)`
- `fav_country(country_id, device_id)`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had to remove the s.country before the from countries part to make it work. (I got "Unknown column 's.country' in 'field list' error.) The query runs under 2 seconds!

Comment: @burakk . . . Ooops.  I didn't notice it there.